# Can we create and play multiple video players with the new Titanium Mobile SDKs?

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, titanium

Can we create multiple video players on single window, Now? As in previous SDKs we had only full screen video players after that we can embed the video player but it can play only last video player. Is that posible now with the availability of new SDK?

I am trying to create multiple video players in a loop. I am using Titanium Mobile SDK 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this module. You might find it helpful for you

https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/736?532321060